# Xhr log Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

i'm using Angularjs with $stateProvider for maningin route and view. I see in console that are a lot of XHR logs and i want to disable it. There is a way to do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOTgr.png)

Comment: It has to be from your console, not from `$stateProvider`

Comment: Yes, but  how can i prevent this type of log?

Comment: It's your personal settings in chrome, you can disable it in webtools

Comment: is there a way to do this from code?

Comment: No, it's developer tools itself, I don't understand your concern. You have turn on this setting, no1 else is going to see the logs unless they turn on the settings too